# GPU on AzureML running out of memory even with very small batch size

Tags: gpu, huggingface-transformers, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I'm finetuning a HuggingFace model with my own data using AzureML.  The size of the dataset is 1.7 MB, and even when I've made batches of 5, I still get the same out of memory errors.  The VM I specify has 28GB RAM, 16 GB of GPU RAM.  I admit I don't know how to calculate the model's memory requirements.

Here's the script I use to launch the job

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Experiment
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget, AmlCompute
from azureml.core.compute_target import ComputeTargetException

from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.runconfig import DockerConfiguration
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies

from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig

# create workspace
ws = Workspace.get(name='', subscription_id='', resource_group='')

# create experiment
experiment_name = 'train-with-data'
experiment = Experiment(workspace = ws, name = experiment_name)

# Create environment
myenv = Environment("myenv")

conda = CondaDependencies()
conda.add_pip_package('transformers[torch]')
conda.add_pip_package('datasets')

myenv.python.conda_dependencies = conda
myenv.register(ws)

docker_config = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)

# Provision compute target
gpu_cluster_name = "gpu-nc4-cluster"

# Verify that cluster does not exist already
try:
    cpu_cluster = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=gpu_cluster_name)
    print('Found existing cluster, use it.')
except ComputeTargetException: 
    compute_config = AmlCompute.provisioning_configuration(vm_size='STANDARD_NC4AS_T4_V3',
                                                           max_nodes=4)
    cpu_cluster = ComputeTarget.create(ws, gpu_cluster_name, compute_config)

cpu_cluster.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='../src', 
                      script='main.py', 
                      compute_target=cpu_cluster, 
                      environment=myenv,
                      arguments=['dataset_batch_5.pkl'],
                      docker_runtime_config=docker_config)
 
run = experiment.submit(config=src)
run
```

And here are the contents of main.py:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorWithPadding, TrainingArguments, Trainer
import pickle
import sys
import os

def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
    # Load the data from the file
        input_data = pickle.load(f)

    print(input_data)

    # I tried this but don't make a difference
    os.environ["PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"] = "max_split_size_mb:64"

    checkpoint = "Salesforce/codegen-350M-mono"
    device = "cuda"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint, trust_remote_code=True).to(device)

    # Data collator - Assembles data into batches for training
    data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

    training_args = TrainingArguments("/trainer")

    trainer = Trainer(
        model,
        training_args,
        train_dataset=input_data["train"],
        eval_dataset=input_data["test"],
        data_collator=data_collator,
        tokenizer=tokenizer
    )

    trainer.train()

    trainer.save_model()

    return "Done"

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The OOM error appears what seems like right after starting trainer.train:

```
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.75 GiB total capacity; 14.74 GiB already allocated; 11.62 MiB free; 15.06 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I did try changing the cuda alloc setting (in main.py), but that didn't make a difference.

Note that I tried running this simple script as a test and it executed successfully:

```
import torch

foo = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
foo = foo.to('cuda')
```

I also tried loading `main.py` into a notebook and running from within AzureML but was having problems with the outdated transformers library that's in AzureML's pre-loaded environment.

I also thought of starting top in the terminal while the job is running but didn't see that option in the AzureML GUI.